# For a quad sprite character in 3d what collision object to use, a mesh collider or a box collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am developing a game concept with moving sprite characters in 3d like a billboard. For this I am planning to use the quad gameobject in Unity. So if it is advised not to use a mesh collider can I use a box collider with zero depth or with a small depth. I seen on other answers that a box collider with small depth will make objects pass through them so is there like a minimum depth if box collider is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use a quad, the dimensions of the mesh collider for quad object will be the same as for the box collider, so use box collider (it is faster).

any collider with small depth (box collider or mesh collider) will let objects that move very fast pass trough them (in case that the fast object is before the collider in one frame and behind the collider in the next frame) if you use collision detection without velocity swept detection (if the collision detection does not create a mesh containing the space swept by the object during first and second frame)

[image]

the minimum depth for a box collider is the distance that your fastest object makes in one frame (if you don't have dynamic collision detection - if you do, it doesn't matter).